# Visual Studio Code - Salto de línea automático

Tags: vscode

Vscode hace un salto de línea automático, quiero desactivarlo pero no encuentro la opción.

Gracias.

[image: error]

Comment: ¿Puedes describir qué otras acciones realizas mientras te sucede esto?

Comment: SOLUCIONADO!

Acabo de darme cuenta de por qué pasa, el salto automático se produce si la línea en la que se esta escribiendo es la final. 

Como se muestra en la imagen cuando escribo en la línea 1 la letra 'a' hace salto, pues bien, si pulso 'enter' creando una segunda y vuelvo a la línea 1 y vuelvo a escribir ya no hace el salto.

Gracias Daniel, me estaba volviendo loco.

Answer (score 1):

Si te refieres a que cuando se le de enter acepte la sugerencia: En windows me sirvió ir a Archivo>Preferencias>Usuario>Editor de texto>Sugerencias y en "Accept Suggestion On Enter" dejarlo en on
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Un poco tarde, pero la solución que encontré fue deshabilitar la extensión "EditorConfig for VS Code"

Ojalá se te haya solucionado, a mí me había vuelto loco

Answer (score 0):

A mi también me estaba volviendo loco eso pero le cambia a false esta opción `insert_final_newline = false` en donde tú dices.